# How to Host .net Core 3.0 Web Api on IIS?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core-3.0, core-api

I am trying to run .net core web Api on Remote PC by hosting it on IIS. I am able to run application locally. Api works fine when it is run through PostMan.

I can run the application using IP address also by using

```
UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "http://localhost:21868","http://*.*.*.*:5000")
```

in `program.cs`(Self hosted Application using kestral).
Set up done in **applicationhost.config**

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:21268:localhost" />
```

I tried to run API without debugging on remote PC by hosting it on IIS but I am unable to do that ?

**EDIT:**

Error I am getting while I am trying to host-

> > Unable to connect to web server iisexpress`and`invalid URl: the hostname could not be parsed.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Have you installed the .net core hosting bundle in the server?

Comment: Have you checked [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)? In-process IIS hosting is the default for new projects. You need to configure IIS, and [install the .NET Core hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle) on the IIS server

Comment: @Shoban I am trying to host it on iis and I am getting the error `Unable to connect to web server iisexpress` and `invalid URl: the hostname could not be parsed`.

Comment: @Priya This looks more like you got eh url wrong. Are you checking locally in the server or from another pc?

Comment: Please attach a screen shot. It is confusing when you said "I am trying to host it on iis", but the error message was "Unable to connect to web server iisexpress". Reveal what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/simple-way-to-host-your-asp-net-core-in-iis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing thing was- Enable **Development time IIS support** while doing set up of Visual studio 2017/2019 as native IIS module is required to run ASP.NET Core applications on **IIS**.

After that I could set the Launch as in `IIS` in Project Properties. Below Link I found helpful to host core application on IIS.

> > https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/

Comment: The option is only available in VS2017, how did you fix 2019?

Comment: @Norcino This option is also available in VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Startup.cs File

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    if (env.IsProduction() || env.IsStaging())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/index.html");
    }

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
    });

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");

        // custom CSS
        c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
    });

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
        {
            ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
        }
    });


    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseCors();

}
```

https://youtu.be/6HiaXCAlRr0